# Sum cells if values in other column are equal

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a formula to sum all ammounts where references from another column are the same. So:

| Amount | Reference | SUM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | 2410 |
| 2300 | 1 | 2410 |
| 410 | 2 | 0 |
| -410 | 2 | 0 |
| 10 | 1 | 2410 |
| -100 | 3 | -100 |

Tried to figure out a way with sumif, no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simple `SUMIFS()` function.

```
=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,B2)
```

Or `SUMIF()`.

```
=SUMIF(B:B,B2,A:A)
```

[image]

Comment: I had a feeling it was super-simple, and it is... Many thanks! :)